# Pearson Chi-squared test and p-value in SAS

Tags: sas, chi-squared

I'm new in SAS and I'm having problems to generate Pearson Chi-squared and p-value. I tried some tutorials and Youtube videos but I failed.

I`d like to use Proc Freq to generate a cross tabulation of the CO2_level and Yield_category variables. Also get the Pearson Chi-squared test statistic and p-value associated with this cross tabulation. However, when I run the code I get only the frequency as an output.

[I have the following table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBKh0.png)

My code is:

```
proc freq data=growth;
    tables CO2_level*Yield_category/nopercent norow testp=(50 25 25);
run;
```

[My result is the following table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBKh0.png)

Can anyone help me to solve that?

Thanks,

Carlos

Comment: Sorry, the result table is wrong. Actually I`m getting only the frequency.

Comment: Please add images in the question body as images (or -even better - as text), not as links.

Answer (score 0):

Add the CHISQ option to the TABLES statement.

Please check the documentation in the future, in particular the examples section such as this, where you can find fully worked examples:
http://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.2&docsetId=procstat&docsetTarget=procstat_freq_examples03.htm&locale=en

```
proc freq data=growth;
    tables CO2_level*Yield_category/nopercent norow testp=(50 25 25)  CHISQ;
run;
```